# Is there a way to get a specific range of results in a DynamoDB query?

Tags: java, amazon-dynamodb, dynamodb-queries

I am querying a DynamoDB table with `table.query()`. I found that a `FilterExpression` can filter the results further, but I can't seem to find a way to simply filter a range of the results.

What I mean is that if the table has say 100 items, and the query matches 20 of them, is there a way to get say items 11-15 from those 20?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: There isn't a way to do that in DynamoDB. If you are wanting to do pagination you may want to think about it differently. DynamoDB supports paging with the `LastEvaluatedKey`/`ExclusiveStartKey`. You don't ask for a specific page, you ask for the next page.

Comment: @JasonWadsworth So this application is an API. Would I need to send the LastEvaluatedKey to the client and include it in the next request to the API in order to get the next set of results?

Comment: Yes. What I've typically seen is that key being stringified and then Base64 encoded. Then you can decode it when you get it back.

Comment: You've hit on one of the major limitations of dynamodb. It will do paging with the LastEvaluatedKey, but you can't request arbitrary page numbers. In the initial result you won't know how many results/pages there are, just that there is another available, and all you can do is get the next page. There are ways to implement arbitrary paging yourself but its messy. Better not to go down that road really.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, both in Query/Scan you can set batch limit(Number of items to want to read).

```
QueryRequest queryRequest = new QueryRequest()
                .withTableName(TABLE_NAME)
                .withKeyConditionExpression("query_condition")
                .withIndexName("index_name") // If you have any
                .withExpressionAttributeValues("Expression_values")
                .withScanIndexForward(false) // To sort the results, only supported in Query. Not in Scan
                .withLimit(LIMIT) // Batch Size/Limit
                .withExclusiveStartKey(lastKeys); // Set the LastEvaluatedKey, if not it can NULL
            
QueryResult result = ddb.query(queryRequest);
Map<String, AttributeValue> lastKeys = result.getLastEvaluatedKey(); // You can pass these keys in your next call
```